# How can I use the EF transaction scope with a SQL Command and only commit both once both succeed?

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, entity-framework

I have an entity framework data context and a SQL command that both need to update and insert objects in the same database. Either both need to succeed or I want to roll back the operation. This seems like the perfect use of transactions but I can't seem to figure out how to use a common transaction between both the SQL Command and the Entity Framework data context that points at a SQL Server 2008 instance. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume you should be able to just wrap both of these actions into a TransactionScope transaction and then complete that or roll that back. The server you execute this on will most likely have to support the Distributed Transaction Coordinator service though.

Comment: You're right. I was missing enabling DTC on the server that I was running this on. Thanks!